# How to implement "group by values" in NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I am using NSMutableArray. I want to fetch the values by date like we do in SQL `group by "log_date"`.

```
logMuArray (
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "4:30pm";
        "log_date" = "11.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "1:30";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "4:33pm";
        "log_date" = "11.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "2:21";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "4:40pm";
        "log_date" = "11.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "5:30";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:30pm";
        "log_date" = "12.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "1:30";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:33pm";
        "log_date" = "12.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "2:21";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:40pm";
        "log_date" = "12.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "5:30";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "07:16pm";
        "log_date" = "19.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "0:07";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:31pm";
        "log_date" = "19.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "0:04";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:33pm";
        "log_date" = "19.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "0:03";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:33pm";
        "log_date" = "19.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "0:06";
    },
        {
        "log_currenttime" = "7:35pm";
        "log_date" = "19.12.2011";
        "log_duration" = "0:05";
    }
)
```

**So, I have just performed....

```
 NSLog(@"logMuArray %@",[logMuArray valueForKey:@"log_date"]);
```

But I want to fetch the UNIQUE dates only.**
I have thought about NSPredicate or Mutable Set etc...

```
logMuArray (
    "11.12.2011",
    "11.12.2011",
    "11.12.2011",
    "12.12.2011",
    "12.12.2011",
    "12.12.2011",
    "19.12.2011",
    "19.12.2011",
    "19.12.2011",
    "19.12.2011",
    "19.12.2011"
)
```

Thanks in advance.....

**EDIT:**

I have also heared about "@distinctUnionOfObjects"

......

Comment: Is it possible to uniquely identify objects based on two or more keys with same logic?

Comment: Your question is good, better you should ask a question, because code is also required, so please ask your question in stack overflow. Side by side I have not much idea upon this, but I need a time to solve it. Will try to solve it, but need a code for solving it. Better you post your question at stack overflow with code. thanks

Comment: it might help you [Rebuild an NSArray by grouping objects w.r.t any matching keys in each dictionary in that array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375528/rebuild-an-nsarray-by-grouping-objects-that-have-matching-id-numbers/38472661#38472661)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Shanti's answer is close. You want to use the Key-Value Coding collection operator [`@distinctUnionOfObjects`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178539). Place the operator immediately preceding the key which you want it to affect, as if it is a part of the key path you are accessing:

```
[logMuArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.log_date"]
```

Notice the use of [`valueForKeyPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000471-CJBIIIEB), not `valueForKey:` The former is a method in the Key-Value Coding protocol, and allows accessing arbitrary depth of attributes. The key path is an `NSString` made up of dot-separated keys. The result of each key lookup is used in turn to access the next key (starting with the original receiver); by default, `valueForKey:` is simply called at each step.

Comment: Can i used it with multiple key path such as  [log_currenttime,log_date]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178521) for this.

```
[logMuArray valueForKey:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.log_date"]
```

edit: Editing this wrt Josh's Response

```
[logMuArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.log_date"]
```

Comment: [logMuArray valueForKeyPath:@"@ distinctUnionOfArrays.log_date"], change valueForKey with valueForKeyPath

Answer (score 3):

You should use `NSSet` for UNIQUE items like :

```
NSSet *filteredData = [NSSet setWithArray:[logMuArray valueForKey:@"log_date"]];
```

Comment: thanks mogs :) But previously Jash Caswell's anser is also nice and prefferable..

Answer (score 1):

Try this logic might help you

```
-(NSMutableArray *) makeUnique :(NSMutableArray *) array {    
    int i;
    int count = [array count];
    for (i =0; i< count ; i++) {
        NSRange range = NSMakeRange (i+1, count); 
        [array removeObject:[array objectAtIndex:i] inRange:range];
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can incorporate a set

Here is some example code

```
NSMutableArray * mArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSDictionary *d1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"foo",@"bar",@"bar",@"oooo",nil];
NSDictionary *d2 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"boo",@"bar",@"bar",@"oooo",nil];
NSDictionary *d3 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"boo",@"bar",@"bar",@"oooo",nil];
[mArray addObject:d1];
[mArray addObject:d2];
[mArray addObject:d3];
NSLog(@"the array\n%@", mArray);
NSLog(@"just bar %@", [mArray valueForKey:@"bar"]);
//get unique values
NSSet * set = [NSSet setWithArray:[mArray valueForKey:@"bar"]];
NSLog(@"unique just bar %@", [set allObjects]);
```

and here is the output

```
2011-12-20 01:50:59.034 TestEnvironment[32401:207] the array
(
        {
        bar = foo;
        oooo = bar;
    },
        {
        bar = boo;
        oooo = bar;
    },
        {
        bar = boo;
        oooo = bar;
    }
)
2011-12-20 01:50:59.036 TestEnvironment[32401:207] just bar (
    foo,
    boo,
    boo
)
2011-12-20 01:50:59.038 TestEnvironment[32401:207] unique just bar (
    foo,
    boo
)
```