# iOS create a new array based on objects in an existing array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array(say expensesArray) of `Expense` objects. expense has property like catId, amount, name etc. Now I want to do something like group by and some other clauses in `SQL`. i.e in new array, my objects should be grouped based on catId and their amount should be added up.
For example, if I have 2 elements in `expensesArray` with `catId=2` and `amount=20` for each then the new array should contain only one element with `catId=2` and `amount=40`.
This is the code that I have tried yet :

```
[groupedExpesesArray addObject:[self createExpenseModel:[expensesArray objectAtIndex:0]]];

ExpenseModel* expenseMObj = [groupedExpesesArray objectAtIndex:0];

for (int j = 1; j < expensesArray.count; j++) 
{            
    ExpenseModel* expModel = [self createExpenseModel:[expensesArray objectAtIndex:j]];

    if ([expModel.categoryID isEqual:expenseMObj.categoryID])
    {
      float amt = [expenseMObj.amount floatValue];
      amt = amt+[expModel.amount doubleValue];
      expenseMObj.amount = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:amt];
    }
    else
    {
      int index = [groupedExpesesArray indexOfObject:expModel];
      if (index == NSNotFound)
      {
         [groupedExpesesArray addObject:expModel];
      }
    }
 }
```

But I am still unable to get the desired value. So I need some guidance here on where I am going wrong here and possible resolving steps.

**Edit:-**
I am creating new object of `Expense` in `createExpenseModel:` method. and checking if it is available in `groupedExpesesArray`. perhaps thats the problem. Isn't it?
Any suggestion would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375528/rebuild-an-nsarray-by-grouping-objects-that-have-matching-id-numbers):

```
NSArray *array = @[@{@"groupId" : @"1", @"price" : @20},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"2", @"price" : @1},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"3", @"price" : @2},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"4", @"price" : @3},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"1", @"price" : @30},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"2", @"price" : @5},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"3", @"price" : @100},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"4", @"price" : @7},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"1", @"price" : @200},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"2", @"price" : @9},
                   @{@"groupId" : @"3", @"price" : @10},
                   ];

NSMutableArray *resultArray = [NSMutableArray new];
NSArray *groups = [array valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.groupId"];
for (NSString *groupId in groups)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *entry = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [entry setObject:groupId forKey:@"groupId"];

    NSArray *groupedEntires = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"groupId = %@", groupId]];
    CGFloat sum = 0;
    for (NSDictionary *dict in groupedEntires)
    {
        NSNumber *price = [dict objectForKey:@"price"];
        sum += [price floatValue];

    }
    [entry setObject:@(sum) forKey:@"price"];
    sum = 0;
    [resultArray addObject:entry];
}
```

Result:

```
{
    groupId = 3;
    price = 112;
},
{
    groupId = 4;
    price = 10;
},
{
    groupId = 1;
    price = 250;
},
{
    groupId = 2;
    price = 15;
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood well but, it could be done by something like this

```
//This will filter the array grouping object by the same ID
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"catID == %d",index];
NSArray * arrayGroup = [expensesArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
//Sum their amount
NSNumber * totalAmount = [arrayGroup valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];
```

You can put that into a loop and recreate the values by taking the first object of each single filtered group array. Probably it's not the fastest way but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a model object class like this:

**Expense.h**

```
NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ExpenseType) {
    ExpenseTypeMeals,
    ExpenseTypeLodging,
    ExpenseTypeTravel
};

@interface Expense : NSObject

@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger categoryID;
@property (assign, nonatomic) float amount;

- (instancetype)initWithCategoryID:(NSUInteger)categoryID amount:(float)amount;
+ (instancetype)expenseWithCategoryID:(NSUInteger)categoryID amount:(float)amount;
@end
```

**Expense.m**

```
@implementation Expense

- (instancetype)initWithCategoryID:(NSUInteger)categoryID amount:(float)amount
{
    if (!(self = [super init])) return nil;
    _categoryID = categoryID;
    _amount = amount;
    return self;
}

+ (instancetype)expenseWithCategoryID:(NSUInteger)categoryID amount:(float)amount
{
    return [[Expense alloc] initWithCategoryID:categoryID amount:amount];
}

- (NSString *)description
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"categoryID: %@, amount: %.2f", @(self.categoryID), self.amount];
}
@end
```

... and given an array of Expense objects like so:

```
NSArray *expenses = @[[Expense expenseWithCategoryID:ExpenseTypeMeals amount:32.50],
                      [Expense expenseWithCategoryID:ExpenseTypeMeals amount:12.95],
                      [Expense expenseWithCategoryID:ExpenseTypeLodging amount:125.45],
                      [Expense expenseWithCategoryID:ExpenseTypeLodging amount:125.45]];
```

... you could then do something similar to the following:

```
// Use Key-Value Coding (KVC) collection operator to obtain an array of category IDs.
NSArray *categoryIDs = [expenses valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.categoryID"];
NSMutableArray *totalsByCategory = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:categoryIDs.count];

for (NSNumber *categoryID in categoryIDs)
{
    // Use a predicate to a filtered array of Expense objects that match the current category ID.
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"categoryID = %@", categoryID];
    NSArray *expensesForCategory = [expenses filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    // Use a KVC collection operator to sum of the amount properties of the Expense objects.
    NSNumber *sum = [expensesForCategory valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.amount"];

    [totalsByCategory addObject:[Expense expenseWithCategoryID:categoryID.intValue amount:sum.floatValue]];
}

NSLog(@"%@", totalsByCategory);
```

... with the the resulting output...

```
2014-08-12 11:08:32.692 MyExpenses[9691:303] (
    "categoryID: 0, amount: 45.45",
    "categoryID: 1, amount: 250.90"
)
```