# How do I populate a UITableView with an NSArray of an NSDictionary of multiple keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsdictionary

I have an NSArray of an NSDictionary:

So my array is called messagesArray and its really an array of a dictionary because i had to to use the dictionary methods to sort the messages by sender name.

Here is what my messagesArray looks like:

```
    {
    MessageBody1 = nmnmn;
    MessageBody2 = kkkjk;
    MessageBody3 = hbjhbjbb;
    MessageBody4 = "Kjnhkbjhbjh ";
    MessageBody5 = "N m jbjbhb";
    MessageBody6 = "";
    MessageBody7 = "Test test test";
    MessageBody8 = "";
    MessageBody9 = "This is a test.";
    senderName = testUser;
    }
```

How would i fill a table view up with all the "MessageBody" keys taking into account that each key is incremented by 1?

Comment: Can you try to make this question more clear... maybe paste NSLog output of the actual data?

Comment: Sorry the code above is the NSLog of messagesArray

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you said you posted code for `messagesArray`, but arrays should be surrounded by parentheses `( )`, not braces `{ }` (braces are for dictionaries), but I'll assume that's a typo.

You should be using the table view's `indexPath` to get the correct object in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Something like this:

`cell.textLabel.text = messagesArray[indexPath.row];`

However, if you did actually mean that `messagesArray` is an array of dictionaries, and the code you posted was an example of the dictionary, there isn't a great way to split up each `MessageBody` into its own cell based on your layout. Instead, the proper layout for something like this would be:

```
> messagesArray //holds all the messages
    > msgArray //one for each message
        > MessageBody strings (however many there are)
```

Then, you can return `messagesArray.count` for the number of sections in your table view, and `[messagesArray[section] count]` for the number of rows in a given section.

The text of each cell would then be something like:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [messagesArray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems its an array of just one dictionary, and you want the (I think) the values in your table, sorted by the numeric part of the keys.  We could wrangle that out of the datasource methods, but it would be much simpler to change the data into what the datasource method wants, which is an array...

```
// add this in your class's private interface
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *datasourceArray;

NSDictionary *messagesArray = // your messagesArray that's really a dictionary
self.datasourceArray = [NSMutableArray array];

NSArray *keys = [[messagesArray allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
for (NSString *key in keys) {
    [datasourceArray addObject:dictionary[key]];
}
```

This takes the keys from the dictionary, sorts them lexically, then grabs each value (in sorted order) and puts them in datasourceArray.

Now your datasource methods will be easy...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.datasourceArray.count;
}
```

And in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:, lookup your cell data with:

```
NSString *message = self.datasourceArray[indexPath.row];
```

Comment: so im trying to implement this but it keeps throwing an error -[__NSArrayM allKeys]: unrecognized selector sent to instance.  im guessing when i set NSDictionary *messagesArray = originalmessagesArray; it was stored as an array and not a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, that error tells us that it's definitely an array which is contrary to what's pasted in the question.  Arrays NSLog with parens (), and dictionaries log with braces {}.

Comment: Well this is odd i put an NSLog right before the code you gave me and it results with {};

Comment: Does it have something to do with the fact that this Array of a dictionary has been sorted exactly how the solution to this question has been? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375528/rebuild-an-nsarray-by-grouping-objects-that-have-matching-id-numbers